# auth_request + login screen vs browser redirects

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

When someone visits a site I want him to have a specific cookie set.
Such cookie is checked via auth_request and a 403 should end up in a login screen (HTML/PHP needed so no auth_basic).
On successful auth it shall redirect to "foo.example.org".
So I wrote a config and things in the proxy that do all of that.

Problem is: The browser enters foo.example.org, remembers the previous redirect and keeps redirecting to the login screen.

What can I change so that the browser does no redirect (out of his cache)?
Something like "foo.example.org?auth" would be a thing or having the auth completely internal.

```
server {

    server_name foo.example.org;

    location / {
        auth_request /restricted;
        error_page 403 = @error403;

        proxy_pass http://10.12.34.56;
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

        proxy_redirect   off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location @error403 {
        return 307 /restricted;
    }

    location /restricted {
        proxy_pass http://auth_server;

        proxy_redirect   off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a `307 Temporary Redirect` response instead of a `403 Forbidden`, it's probably just cached in the browser so keeps redirecting. It's just doing what you are telling it to do.

You are making life hard for yourself anyway, it's actually much easier to do this.

Use a map directive to check for the cookie and set a custom variable based on the value of it. Lets assume they need cookie `secret` to have the value `password` to get in:

```
map $cookie_secret $notloggedin {
  default  1;
  password 0;
}
```

Now `$notloggedin` will always be set to `1` unless the client request has cookie `secret=password`, then it will be set to `0` which in Nginx also equates to empty/unset.

Now we drop that variable into an if condition in the location block. There is some confusion over the use of if conditions in locations and lots of people will tell you that you shouldn't use them, but [the docs](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) clearly state:

> The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in a location
>   context are:
>
> return ...; 
>   rewrite ... last;

So this will be ok.

```
location / {
  if ($notloggedin) {
    return https://example.com/login;
  }
```

People without the cookie now get redirected to the login page.

Comment: Thanks for writing. Is it normal that this way opens the basic auth anyway? Or did I do something wrong then? I was thinking that the unauthorized client sees the custom login screen. But now I see the basic auth login and after that the custom login screen.

Comment: I actually realised I was also making it harder than it needed to be. I've edited my answer